# What is this operation called (assessment of whether value is high or low for given set)

Tags: terminology

Suppose we have set of values and one arbitrary. Then we perform an ... I don't know what call this... an index of a value in this way:

$$
    \frac{x-\text{min}}{\text{max}-\text{min}}
$$

So for given set we can see if we are dealing with values that are high or low for particular boundaries of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it "normalization". The idea is that you are taking a range of values and scaling and translating them to lie in a standard ("normal") range of $0$ to $1$.

Though I am not very familiar with  statistics, I believe this is the standard terminology. For example, see [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling), or just google `normalizing data 0 to 1`.